# How do you use classification algorithms in a sentiment analysis?

Tags: sentiment-analysis

Classification algorithms (logistic regression, SVM, etc) work on $(x, y)$ data where $y$ is a categorical (often binary) response and $x$ is a multi-variate predictor.

How are these algorithms applied to a sentiment analysis problem? I get that $y$ is just a binary response on whether the sentiment is "positive" or "negative", but what are the $x$ variables?

Each sentence consists of words, and that's all we have to go by, so is each individual word a possible predictor variable in our model? That does not seem very tractable.

Comment: Why would it not be tractable?

Comment: I said "seem". And yes, having hundreds of thousands of predictor variable does not "seem" tractable. That's almost true by definition.